# The Android app crashes when you want to check your achievements

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

Recently I started to use the Stack Overflow Android application and I noticed the app crashes when I want to check my achievements.

- Phone: Samsung Galaxy S8+
- Android: 7.0
- Security patch: October 2017
- Stack Overflow app version: 1.0.4

Comment: You have no acheivements and it's a null pointer exception? :)

Comment: @MartinJames Hahaha I have some achievements :P However I tried to get the error from the Android Device Monitor but I can't reproduce the bug anymore :/

I didn't have those achievements yesterday, might be why the bug happened. However when I want to have more details on a badge I earned, I got this error: `The mapper function returned a null value.`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as @Martin James [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359695/the-android-app-crashes-when-you-want-to-check-your-achievements#comment534353_359695), the answer has to be that you had no achievements. I experienced the same crash when I didn't have them, the app used to crash earlier, but now since I have got achievements, it does not crash.